Adding NextAuthV5 Middleware gives TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
I am using next 14.2.4 and next-auth 5. Whenever I add my middleware file
export { auth as middleware } from '@/auth';

export const config = {
   matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)']
};

attempting to load any page gives this error

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User')

I believe it has something to do with auth.js file though.

import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { getUserFromDb } from "./queries/mongoQueries";

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
providers: \[
Credentials({
// You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
credentials: {
email: {},
password: {},
},
authorize: async (credentials) =\> {
let user = null

                // logic to salt and hash password
    
                // logic to verify if user exists
                user = await getUserFromDb(credentials.email, credentials.password)
    
                if (!user) {
                    // No user found, so this is their first attempt to login
                    // meaning this is also the place you could do registration
                    throw new Error("[auth.js]: User not found.")
                }
    
                // return user object with the their profile data
                return user
            },
        }),
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login",
    },

});

I am using mongoDb for the back end the 'getUserFromDb' fetches the user from the db

export async function getUserFromDb(email: string, password: string) {
await connectToMongoDB();

const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });

if (!user) {
throw new Error('\[Query\]: User not found');
}

const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
if (!passwordMatch) {
throw new Error('\[Query\]: Password does not match');
}

return user;

}

The web app works perfectly fine without the middleware file existing. The user is able to register, login and logout. Adding the middleware completely breaks the webapp.
I attempted changing the middleware file to not protect any pages and it still continued to give the error.
